# does/could something like a realtime Linux container exist?

Tags: real-time, container

Is there some way to configure a Linux container (ie. cgroups/namespace-isolated process tree) to have realtime characteristics - ideally to the point to be suitable for industrial machine control / robotics and alike?

Maybe it's not related to containers in any way and one always gives single processes realtime capabilities? OTOH, such a container may contain a completely different (RT?)Linux distribution and may have exclusive access to one core of a multi-core processor?

I'm not having any concrete use case at the moment, just wondering if / how well Linux could replace an [PLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller).

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, but probably not, and it depends on your requirements.

"Realtime" refers to a concept of low latency--that is, in theory, it means "no latency", but in practice reaching *no* latency is impossible to achieve; after all, there is always some processing to be done before an input can generate some sort of output, and so there will always be *some* latency, even if it's just one clock cycle.

However, there is latency and then there's latency, and they're seven different things ;-)

It is possible to reduce the latency on a Linux system by changing a process' priority or its scheduling queue, and/or by switching to a low-latency C library, and doing so will already fulfill the requirements of *some* forms of a "realtime" setup. If that's all you need to do, then sure, using a container will allow you to separate the low-latency parts of your system from the rest (provided you allow processes in that container to modify their scheduling priority), and you shouldn't see much difference.

It may be that you need to do more, however. There are more ways to modify your latency. In order of 'least work' to 'most work', I know of:

- There are a few boot-time options in most default distribution kernels that you can set, which change the way the scheduler works so that latency is reduced (although average *performance* might suffer)
- There are a number of compile-time options that you can set, too (although many have now been changed to boot-time options, there are still a few of them left)
- There are (or at least, used to be when I last checked) a number of low-latency patches floating around that allow even more drastic realtime requirements to be fulfilled.

If you need one of these, then a container will not help you, since a container still uses the same kernel as the rest of your system.

Having said all that, while it is under some circumstances *possible* to run a real-time application in a container along with other things on the same system, I would recommend against doing so. Running multiple things on the same system will most likely the latency of applications running on the system; so even if you do allow a container to do what it needs to do, the system might not be able to keep up.

Comment: I guess "realtime" usually refers to a very low and, most importantly, somewhat guaranteed maximum latency. AFAIK process execution can be limited to certain (logical) processors, thus giving the possibility to dedicate one processor exclusively to one process/container. That, combined with the RT_PREEMPT Kernel patch sounds promising to me - what di you think?

Comment: @UdoG I totally agree with you. Did you do some more research on this question?

Comment: Unfortinately not...